# Disable other Bootstrap-datepicker view modes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

In Bootstrap-datepicker, whenever I click on the calendar title (February 2014) in the header it takes you to the "months of the year" view mode. Is there a way to disable the ability to view other view modes or turning off the link without editing the plugin file?

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you manage to sort this out?

Comment: @Norbert: Did you resolve this issue without comment out bootstrap-datetimepicker code?

Comment: Nope, not yet.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You may search for this code in bootstrap-datepicker:

```
  case 'picker-switch':
    showMode(1);
  break;
```

and comment out the showMode() line.

If you feel like making a contribution to bootstrap-datepicker I guess i is trivial to make the execution of this line depend on a custom option.